# Login with if condition doesnt works MVC Spring java

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, authentication, request

Im working on an app that should have a log in screen so I did a very basic just for testing, but it doesn't works. and I debugged but I still don't get the problem, would you help me.
This is the code of the controller, it has a very basic if condition but It doesn't works, I send the variables to the console, because I thought the variables were in blank but I get the variables. so I don't know what to do.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ingreso.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView ingreso(
          @RequestParam("usuario") String usuario,
          @RequestParam("clave") String clave,
          HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    String destino;


        logger.info(usuario);
        logger.info(clave);

      if(usuario.toString()=="295325" && clave.toString()=="7512"){
          mv.addObject("usuario", usuario);
          destino = "reservacion";
          mv.setViewName(destino);
          }
      else{
          destino = "login";
          mv.addObject("error", "usuario invalido :'v");
          mv.setViewName(destino);
          }

    return mv;
  }
```

Login.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="ingreso.htm">
        <label>Numero de cuenta</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="usuario" type="number" max-length="4" required>
        <label>Nip</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="clave" type="password"  required>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: It always says incorrect user "usuario Incorrecto"

Comment: Is your controller mapped to a URL path?

Comment: yes, I actually tested if condition with (TRUE ) and it change the view, but not when I try String vs String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings comparison must be with `.equals()`

**correct**

```
if(usuario.equals(usu) && clave.equals(pwd))
```

**incorrect**

```
if(usuario==(usu) && clave==(pwd))
```